# Position:fixed Upsets Width:100% on Mobiles

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want the header on my web page to remain visible as the user scrolls, so I have given it the CSS

```
body{
width: 100%
}
#header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%
}
```

The problem I have is that on mobiles the header actually ends up with a width greater than the screen so the page can be scrolled sideways slightly, which is clearly undesirable.

According to Chrome Developer Tools, the header has a width of 396.5px in a 375px screen, 434px on a 414px screen and 774px on a 768px screen.

I've tried changing width to inherit on both the body and the header. I've tried removing content in case something is forcing the header to overflow. None of these things work. The only way to get the width right is to change position of the header to anything other than fixed but of course they don't provide the characteristic I want.

Why is this? And is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I'd need to see your full styling CSS and your markup to know for sure where the issue lies, but it seems like you probably have 10px padding on the left and right of ``#header``, but that element does not have ``box-sizing: border-box;`` to account for padding in the element's total width.

Answer (score 0):

Without setting a `margin`, `padding` and `box-sizing` property, each element has its own, so that's what is messing with your code.

Reset all by adding this to top of code:

```
/* you can use #header to reset only your header */
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```